# Como usar o resultado de um select para montar outro?

Tags: sql-server, sql-select

Eu montei um select que concatena uma String. Quero usar o resultado desse select em outro select

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT('caminho da tabela') AS caminho FROM tabela) AS result
```

Pode fazer assim? Como posso usar?

Answer (score 7):

Faz direto:

```
select * 
  from (select * from TABELA1) AS r
 where r.campo = 'eu'
```

**ATUALIZANÇÃO FEITA DEPOIS DA ATUALIZAÇÃO DA PERGUNTA**

A sua sub consulta retorna uma tabela com uma coluna, para usar isso no select de fora é só usar `caminho`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT('caminho da tabela') AS caminho FROM tabela) AS result
WHERE result.caminho = 'variavel'
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO APÓS COMENTÁRIO**

Achei como executar o sql quando ele é uma string nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059520/3517631):

Para o seu problema talvez possa montar um insert do resultado na tabela destino, executar como na reposta linkada e pegar o valor da tabela.

Comment: Preciso que seja feito uma consulta com o resultado da subconsulta. Se me entende.

Comment: É o que o SQL acima faz... uma consulta no resultado de `select * from TABELA1` ...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta levando em conta sua atualização da pergunta.

Comment: Humm. Só que o resultado não é o esperado. O que eu preciso é isso SELECT * FROM server1.database1.tabela1. Esse "server1.database1.tabela1" é que o subselect concatena, e o resultado final é apenas o caminho.

Comment: Você quer transformar uma string (vinda de um sql) em um comando mesmo. Nesse caso acho que o maximo que você pode fazer é retornar um SQL inteiro na string e tentar executar ele. Isso está na aplicação ou está dentro de um procedimento no BD?

Comment: Está executando dentro do BD.

Comment: Edite a resposta, acho que com o link que tem lá você consegue chegar a uma solução.

Answer (score 3):

Apesar da resposta do Ricardo funcionar, esta abordagem pode tornar uma consulta confusa.

por exemplo, vamos imaginar a seguinte consulta hipotetica:

```
SELECT 
    c.id
    c.descricao
    d.descricao as alt,
FROM tabelaD as d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(a.id, b.id) as id
        ISNULL(a.descricao, b.descricao) as id 
    from (
        SELECT
            a.id,
            a.descricao
        FROM tabelaA as a
    ) a
    full join (
        SELECT
            b.id,
            b.descricao
        FROM tabelaB as b
    ) b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.id is null OR b.id is null
) as c ON d.id = c.id
```

Para ajudar a organiza esta consulta (e muitas outras), podemos usar uma CTE (common table expression):

```
with CTE_A AS (
    select 
        a.id,
        a.descricao
    from tabelaA as a
), CTE_B AS (
    select 
        b.id,
        b.descricao
    from tabelaB as b
), CTE_C AS (
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(a.id, b.id) as id
        ISNULL(a.descricao, b.descricao) as id 
    from CTE_A a
    full join CTE_B b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.id is null OR b.id is null
)

SELECT 
    c.id
    c.descricao
    d.descricao as alt,
FROM tabelaD as d
LEFT JOIN CTE_C as c ON d.id = c.id
```

para o seu caso, você pode ter algo assim:

```
WITH CTE_TEXT AS (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT('caminho da tabela') AS caminho 
    FROM tabela
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_TEXT AS result
```

**EDIT**

Vendo o seu comentario em outra resposta, vejo que o que deseja não é reutilizar uma consulta, mas montar uma consulta de forma dinamica.

```
DECLARE @tabela nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @coluna nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT 
    @tabela = (SELECT CONCAT('nome da tabela') AS tabela,
    @coluna = (SELECT CONCAT('nome da coluna') AS coluna
FROM consultas;    

SET @query = '
    SELECT *
    FROM {tabela} as a  
    WHERE a.{coluna} = @valor
';

SET @query = REPLACE(@query , '{tabela}', @tabela);
SET @query = REPLACE(@query , '{coluna}', @coluna);

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@valor varchar', @valor= 'valor'
```

Note que a variavel `@query` armazena uma string com a sua consulta dinamica.

Nomes de `tabelas` e `colunas` que serão inseridos de forma dinamica estão entre `{}` e depois fazemos a substiuição dos mesmos com um `REPLACE`, utilizei `{}` apenas por conveniencia, pois o C# e o JavaScript utilizam esta notação para interpolação de Strings, você pode usar a marcação que preferir.

Enquanto os filtros o ideal é que passe eles como parametros da consulta, para tal terá de colocar um `@` antes do nome de cada parametro, no exemplo acima estou usando `@valor` como parametro. Lembre-se de declarar o mesmo no segundo argumento do `sp_executesql`, no exemplo acima o meu `@valor` é do tipo `varchar` e recebe o valor `valor`.

Comment: Exato, algo dinâmico. Em @coluna o valor seria o filtro?

Comment: @EmanuelF, adicionei uma explicação sobre a consulta dinamica.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que é isto que está precisando:

```
DROP TABLE TabelaComandosSQL;/*Se já existir*/

/*Cria uma tabela para teste -----INÍCIO-----*/
CREATE TABLE TabelaComandosSQL(
[Codigo] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_TabelaComandosSQL]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[Comando] [nvarchar](MAX)
);
GO
/*Cria uma tabela para teste -----FIM-----*/

/*Cria uma registro (que seria um comando sql) -----INÍCIO-----*/
INSERT TabelaComandosSQL ([Codigo], [Comando]) VALUES (0, 'SELECT * FROM TabelaComandosSQL')
/*Cria uma registro (que seria um comando sql) -----FIM-----*/


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
/*Faz uma busca na tabela TabelaComandosSQL retornando o comando que deve ser executado*/
SET @SQL = (SELECT TOP 1 [Comando] FROM TabelaComandosSQL)

SELECT (@SQL) [Texto da Consulta];    /*<-Esta linha apenas mostra o comando que foi inserido na tabela TabelaComandosSQL*/
EXEC (@SQL);                        /*<-Esta linha executa o comando que foi inserido na tabela TabelaComandosSQL*/
```

Comment: Realmente funciona! Mas apenas não funciona quando temos mais de um resultado na tabela de commandos.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "resultado"? Pois a consulta que fiz de exemplo tem um TOP 1, que deixa vir apenas um resultado por vez. Basta fazer o filtro adequado na cláusula WHERE para encontrar o comando SQL correto. 
Porém, se você quis dizer, mais de um comando sql no mesmo registro e na mesma coluna, basta cadastrá-los utilizando o separador ";". Desta forma, todos os comandos válidos serão executados.